# What does the `<>` in Rails query mean?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am having a hard time searching meaning of symbols like what `<>` means in rails querying. So what does `<>` mean? (or in general, how do you google search for things like `<>`?)

## Nutshell

In plain English, what do the following queries mean?

Query 1:

```
@profile.socials.all.where.not(kind: [2, 3])
```

Query 2:

```
@profile.socials.where("kind <> ?", "[:facebook, :linked_in]")
```

Note 1: `kind` is of data type `enum` that looks like this:

```
enum kind: [ :twitter, :google_plus, :facebook, :linked_in, :skype, :yahoo ]
```

Note 2: both queries produce the same result in console window. I believe both queries aims to do a `where` query to subset data (with the not-equal-to operator). I just have no clues on know how to interpret that `<>`.

## Detail Rails App

These are my models:

Model `Profile`:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :socials, as: :sociable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :socials, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Model `Social`:

```
class Social < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum kind: [ :twitter, :google_plus, :facebook, :linked_in, :skype, :yahoo ]
  belongs_to :sociable, polymorphic: true
  validates_presence_of :kind
  validates_presence_of :username
end
```

Migration files:

```
class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end


class CreateSocials < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :socials do |t|
      t.integer :kind, null: false
      t.string :username
      t.references :sociable, polymorphic: true, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :socials, :kind
    add_index :socials, :username
  end
end
```

This is what my schema looks like:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160311132502) do

  create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "socials", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "kind",          null: false
    t.string   "username"
    t.integer  "sociable_id"
    t.string   "sociable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end

  add_index "socials", ["kind"], name: "index_socials_on_kind"
  add_index "socials", ["sociable_type", "sociable_id"], name: "index_socials_on_sociable_type_and_sociable_id"
  add_index "socials", ["username"], name: "index_socials_on_username"

end
```

## Console input

```
@profile = Profile.new
@profile.first_name = parameter[:profile][:first_name]
@profile.last_name = parameter[:profile][:last_name]
@profile.socials_attributes = parameter[:profile][:socials_attributes]
@profile.save
@profile = Profile.last
@profile.socials.kinds
@profile.socials.all.where(kind: 2) # => gives you the user facebook account
@profile.socials.all.where(kind: :facebook) # => Apparently only works in Rails 5 or above.

@profile.socials.all.where(kind: [2, 3]) # => gives you the user facebook and linked_in account
@profile.socials.all.where(kind: [:facebook, :linked_in]) # => Apparently only works in Rails 5 or above.
```

## Console Tips - Rails 4 workaround (no need in Rails 5)

*These two queries are equivalent (select only the user's facebook account):*

```
@profile.socials.all.where(kind: 2)

@profile.socials.all.where(kind: @profile.socials.kinds.keys.find_index("facebook"))
```

*These two queries are equivalent (select only the user's facebook and linked_in account):*

```
@profile.socials.all.where(kind: [2, 3])

@profile.socials.all.where(kind: [@profile.socials.kinds.keys.find_index("facebook"), @profile.socials.kinds.keys.find_index("linked_in")])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<>` is SQL syntax, not Ruby or Rails. It means `not equal to`. It is basically the same as `!=` in Ruby.

One subtlety of `<>` in SQL is its behavior with `NULL`s. In SQL, comparing anything to `NULL` gives `NULL`. For instance in Postgres:

```
=> select 1<>1, 1<>2, 1<>null, null<>1, null<>null;
 ?column? | ?column? | ?column? | ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------+----------+----------+----------
 f        | t        | NULL     | NULL     | NULL
```

Notice how even the last expression is `NULL`! Often this is not what you want, and you can instead use `IS DISTINCT FROM`:

```
=> select null is distinct from 1, null is distinct from null;
 ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------
 t        | f
```

**EDIT:** To address your follow-up question: in your database `kind` is an integer. So you want to compare it with integers:

```
@profile.socials.where.not(kind: [2, 3])
```

Or if you are using [Rails 5](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

```
@profile.socials.where.not(kind: [:facebook :linked_in])
```

The above works because Rails 5 will automatically use your `enum` declaration to convert those symbols into the appropriate integers.

Comment: Oh yes `<>` indeed means `not equal to` in SQLIte (where this Rails App is built on). Based on the query though it however seems to imply the opposite? e.g. both `@profile.socials.where("kind <> ?", "[:facebook, :linked_in]")`  and `@profile.socials.all.where(kind: [2, 3])` are returning observations **where the social media types are of** `kind: 2` (`:facebook`) or `kind: 3` (`:linked_in`). Or have I missed something? (ps I have only used Ruby/Rails for 2 months and still a newbie :)

Comment: Actually, I'm not quite sure if `@profile.socials.where("kind <> ?", "[:facebook, :linked_in]")` is actually correct / incorrect... let me check...

Comment: Thanks for the help! This part is working: `@profile.socials.all.where(kind: [2, 3])` (giving me `:facebook` and `:linked_in` accounts), likewise `@profile.socials.all.where(kind: [2])` giving me `:facebook` account only. I guess what I was trying to do (for my own curiosity sake :), is to construct an equivalent query (making advantage of enum), in which I can do something like `@profile.socials.all.where(kind: [:facebook, :linked_in])` and`@profile.socials.all.where(kind: [:facebook])` - i.e. instead of `where kind is one of these numbers`, I say `where kind is one of these english symbols`

Comment: Okay I realized you are querying against `kind`, not `sociable_type`, so I've updated my edit. Although it seems bug-prone to have both `kind` and `sociable_type`, since they are redundant and you'll have to keep them in sync. And once you have data in your database you can't ever reorder your enum.

Comment: Thanks again! (really appreciate it). The bit that I don't quite understand is, how come `@profile.socials.where(kind: 2)` returns the user's facebook account, whereas `@profile.socials.where(kind: :facebook)` returns nothing.  (I wonder if it's something to do with the enum syntax?)

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? It looks like in [4.2](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) you must use integers, but in [5](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) you can use symbols.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm on Rails 4.2.x - probably explained it!

Comment: I edited my answer to show the difference between 4.2 and 5.

Comment: Excellent! Also updated Github repos for reference - https://github.com/Atlas7/params101

Comment: Just discovered a (probably not so elegant solution). i.e. the equivalent of `@profile.socials.where(kind: 2)` is `@profile.socials.all.where(kind: @profile.socials.kinds.keys.find_index("facebook"))` in Rails 4.

Comment: That is verbose but it is clearer than just asking for `2`.

Comment: Totally agreed - good to know in Rails things may be easier. Likewise, the equivalent of `@profile.socials.all.where(kind: [2, 3])`, is `@profile.socials.all.where(kind: [@profile.socials.kinds.keys.find_index("facebook"), @profile.socials.kinds.keys.find_index("linked_in")])` ... oh my have I just spent hours on this? :-)